# Is it possible to use CMD + CLICK Element A + CLICK Element B

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I cannot use the Katalon recorder to click on the Element with CMD Key. Is it possible to click on two different items while the CMD key is pressed?

I tried to do that with sendKeys, controlKeyDown, keyDown Commands and then call Click Command on first element and then call Click Command on second element. But nothing happens.

Also, if we can simulate with CLICK Element A then CMD + CLICK Element B it can be ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Katalon Studio (not the recorder) switch to script mode:

[image]

Now you can write scripts in Groovy!

Next, try using Actions class, like this:

```
WebUI.openBrowser("url of the page you are testing")

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver() 

WebElement targetA = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("element-a-selector"))
WebElement targetB = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("element-b-selector"))

targetA.click()
Actions actions = new Actions(driver)

actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(targetB).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Note that this is your second scenario, first clicking element A (you will need to add the CSS selector or any other way of identifying it) and then holding CTRL and clicking element B.

The first one (press CTRL, click element a, click element b, release CTRL) is similar, just change the last line to:

```
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(targetA).click(targetB).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

and remove `targetA.click()`.

You will need to import the following Selenium helper classes:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement 
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

Comment: Hi Mate, I can not test this because Katalon studio can not perform other actions web recorder can perform other actions but this code not working on browser plugin.

Comment: @MustafaYakut Sorry, this code is for Katalon Studio, not the Recorder. But anyway, I would encourage you to try the Studio version, it is not that big of a change.